# read from android SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferencescreen

I know it's been asked before, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have an XML file `preferences.xml` in the folder `res\xml`. It contains an optionscreen like so:

```
<PreferenceScreen>
  <EditTextPreference
                android:name="prfEmail"
                android:summary="Your account's e-mail address"
                android:title="E-mail"
                android:key="prfEmail" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I can make an activity from it and it shows fine. Now I'd like to read values from these preferences, but I can't seem to find it. In another activity I do:

```
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
appSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String restoredText = appSharedPrefs.getString("prfEmail",null);
```

Whan I'd like to print this value it gives `null` back. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app preferences are stored in the default `SharedPreferences`. You can access them with :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```